# laravel controller Doesn't exists

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

**Route**

```
Route::get('all-news', 'BlogController@allNews')->name('firstfunction');
```

**BlogController**

```
public function allNews()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('tarek')->with([
        'mydata' => $posts,
    ]);
}
```

**Error**

> **Class App\Http\Controllers\BlogController does not exist**

Comment: do you have namespace in your controller

Comment: like this: ```namespace App\Http\Controllers;```

Comment: share all code from `BlogController` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you saved your file in correct location

Answer (score 1):

first check your address there is BlogController.php in : `app/http/controllers/` folder
then check your namespace in your BlogController.php :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

check your BlogController name and finally `composerdump autoload`